# array.splice deletes wrong value and keeps wrong value

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I want to have an array with guests who do NOT have "decline" as a response. So, Tooth Fairy is deleted (shouldn't, she "accepted" the invitation) from the array and Jack Frost stays (shouldn't, he "declined" the invitation).

```
function getAttendees(peopleInvited, responses){
    var coming=peopleInvited;
  responses.map(function(cell){
      if (cell.response=='declined') {
        coming.splice(0,1);
         }         
      });
    return coming;  
}

var people = ['Easter Bunny', 'Tooth Fairy', 'Frosty the Snowman', 
              'Jack Frost', 'Cupid', 'Father Time'];
var responses = [ 
     {name: 'Easter Bunny', response: 'declined'}, 
     {name: 'Jack Frost', response: 'declined'}, 
     {name: 'Tooth Fairy', response: 'accepted'} 
   ];

getAttendees(people, responses);
```

Comment: Why do you think that `0, 1` would know the "right" value?

Comment: I thought the 0 in splice(0,1) meant "start counting from the "declined cell" onwards. May bad.

Comment: neither `coming` nor `splice` nor `0` or `1` know about the declines or the `cell`  in the `responses` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the index of the person in the coming array and then use splice to remove that person based on it's index.

```
function getAttendees(peopleInvited, responses){
  var coming=peopleInvited;
  responses.map(function(cell){
    if (cell.response=='declined') {
      var index = coming.indexOf(cell.name);
      coming.splice(index, 1);
    }         
  });
  return coming;  
}

var people = ['Easter Bunny', 'Tooth Fairy', 'Frosty the Snowman', 
     'Jack Frost', 'Cupid', 'Father Time'];
var responses = [ 
  {name: 'Easter Bunny', response: 'declined'}, 
  {name: 'Jack Frost', response: 'declined'}, 
  {name: 'Tooth Fairy', response: 'accepted'} 
];

getAttendees(people, responses);
```

Comment: In case `var coming=peopleInvited;` was intended in the original code to 'copy' the array so that the original is unmodified, note that this line may need to be changed to `var coming = peopleInvited.slice(0);`, which results in a copy/clone.

Comment: thx, last thing: console.log(index); prints out 0 and 2. Why 2? Shouldn't it be 0 and 1 as Easter Bunny" and "Jack Frost" "declined"?

Comment: I believe that's because indexOf is operating on the 'coming' array (which should be a copy of 'people'). In that array, your two declines are index 0 and 3. However, when the function identifies the first at 0, it removes that element from the array, shifting the others down. This makes 'Jack Frost', who was previously index 3, become index 2, which is where it finds him and prints '2' before removing him.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the responses array to an object using the names of the people as keys instead. I think that's a bit simpler to manage.

```
function getAttendees(people, responses) {
    for (var i = 0, l = people.length, out = []; i < l; i++) {
        var response = responses[people[i]];
        if (!response || response && response === 'accepted') {
            out.push(people[i]);
        }
    }
    return out;
}

var people = ['Easter Bunny', 'Tooth Fairy', 'Frosty the Snowman',
    'Jack Frost', 'Cupid', 'Father Time'];

var responses = {
    'Easter Bunny': 'declined',
    'Jack Frost': 'declined',
    'Tooth Fairy': 'accepted'
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kynxxrnz/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the order they are listed in the different arrays is different.

First you find the "Easter Bunny" on the `responses` array, and you delete the first occurrence from `coming` array without checking what it is. In this case, it corresponds.

Then, you find "decline" by "Jack Frost" and you delete the first (new) occurrence from `coming`, which is now "Tooth Fairy".

Either change the order so both of the arrays will have the same order, or code it differently to not rely on order (which is better in my opinion).